wrong output in terminal than intended in my vscode python
i may have done something wrong in the setting. enter image description here
previously to check print statement i wrote print("b") and the code fine with b as output but now if i clear the print("b") and write print("a") the terminal shows output "b" only. i am fairly new to vscode also

From your terminal, it looks like you stand in the py folder but you call py/demo.py file. Are you sure, you are running the correct python script?

i got it. i should have auto save it. from setting> auto save. thank you for you time

I believe you need to save it. If it is just a print statement should be fine. Also, please restart vscode and the terminal. I also recommend seeing if you have multiple terminals running then you should probably delete them.

i got it. i should have auto save it. from setting> auto save. thank you for you time
